# PayPal gateway has rejected request. Item amount is invalid (#10431)

Tags: magento2, paypal, payment

when I place order in review page paypal throw error

> PayPal gateway has rejected request. Item amount is invalid (#10431:
>   Transaction refused because of an invalid argument. See additional
>   error messages for details).

I don't know why this happens and in error log I found

> [2019-01-05 06:59:09] main.CRITICAL: PayPal NVP gateway errors: Item
>   amount is invalid (#10431: Transaction refused because of an invalid
>   argument. See additional error messages for details). Correlation ID:
>   ad29a838e6cf8. Version: 72.0. [] [] [2019-01-05 06:59:09]
>   main.CRITICAL: Exception message: PayPal gateway has rejected request.
>   Item amount is invalid (#10431: Transaction refused because of an
>   invalid argument. See additional error messages for details).

Comment: Some setting is being enabled by the Paypal site, this information Given by ticket which I created. When they enable some setting it works for me. No coding error at all.

Comment: which setting is ?

Comment: No I didn't do anything they change something at their end.